# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot re-assign $this in ../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php with PHP 7.1

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, php-7

I'm using **magento C.E. 1.9.1.0** and **PHP 7.1** and I get the following error when I visit a category page:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot re-assign $this in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php Line 215
```

This error happens here (Line 215):

```
extract ($this->_viewVars, EXTR_SKIP);
```

This is due to [dynamic calls being forbidden in PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php)

Does anyone knows of a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. copy app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
2. in app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php comment out line 215 and add line 216 as shown below:

   ```
   215         #extract ($this->_viewVars, EXTR_SKIP);                                                                                                                               
   216         foreach($this->_viewVars as $k => $v) if(!isset(${$k}) && $k != 'this') ${$k} = $v;
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same effect as extract, now I get the same error message but at this line: ${$k} = $v;

Comment: try adding $k != 'this' as shown above and report back.

Comment: Adding $k != 'this' fix the problem. I will accept the answer after a few days as I would like to test thoroughly and get different ideas for this.